# Perl one liner is not working inside perl script

Tags: perl

I'm trying to remove the string **@my.mail.com** from the file - list.txt,  using the one liner from my perl script.
(Perl script is kicked off from windows server)

```
r12355  test@my.mail.com
r29555  test@my.mail.com
r29555  trial@my.mail.com
    @my.mail.com
r295721 xxx@my.mail.com
r295722 yyyy@my.mail.com
    @my.mail.com
r295140 test@my.mail.com
r295145 test@my.mail.com
    @my.mail.com
```

Below are the options  I have tried while calling inside the perl script:

```
`perl -pi.bak -e 's/\s+\@my\.mail\.com\s+//g;' D:\\myfolder\\list.txt`;

system("perl -pi.bak -e 's/\s+\@my\.mail\.com\s+//g;' D:\\myfolder\\list.txt");

system( q( perl -l -pi.bak -e 's/\s+\@my\.mail\.com\s+//g;' D:\\myfolder\\list.txt ) );
```

I'm expecting result like

```
r12355  test@my.mail.com
r29555  test@my.mail.com
r29555  trial@my.mail.com
r295721 xxx@my.mail.com
r295722 yyyy@my.mail.com
r295140 test@my.mail.com
r295145 test@my.mail.com
```

Not sure If I'm missing something silly , any inputs are really appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can I suggest: Not. Just write some perl, and don't use perl to start perl

Comment: 2nd and 3rd example has "mgd" instead of "my". Also I think you might need to use `\\\@my` in 1st and 2nd examples because of double interpolation (backticks/quotes and `s///`)

Comment: @Markus Laire : Sorry ,edited the question.TYPO

Comment: If your file needs simple operations, you can use text editors like vim to do such operations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems here. Firstly you have escaped the backslashes in the file path but not in the regex pattern, and secondly you have used single quotes around the parameter to the `-e` option, which Windows doesn't recognise as delimiters

This variation should work for you. It uses single quotes (actually `q{...}`) to protect the backslashes so that *nothing* needs to be escaped

```
system q{perl -pi.bak -e "s/\s+\@my\.mail\.com\s+//g" D:\myfolder\list.txt};
```

However it is poor practice to shell out to another perl process from within your Perl program. It can be done directly in your main code by adding this, which is much more readable and less easy to get wrong

```
{
    local @ARGV = 'D:\myfolder\list.txt';
    local $^I = '.bak';

    while ( <> ) {
        s/\s+\@my\.mail\.com\s+//g;
        print;
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect , thanks a ton. and for the best practice suggestion!